# libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: libraries

I am trying to install ODBC driver for Debian according to those instructions: https://blog.afoolishmanifesto.com/posts/install-and-configure-the-ms-odbc-driver-on-debian/

However, when I type  `sqlcmd -S localhost`, I get the error `libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

What to do? I tried

1. ```
   $ cd /usr/lib 
   $ sudo ln -s libssl.so.0.9.8 libssl.so.10
   $  sudo ln -slibcrypto.so.0.9.8 libcrypto.so.10
   ```
2. Add `/usr/local/lib64` to the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/doubango.conf` file
3. ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
   cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
   sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
   sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
   ```
4. ```
   sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
   ```

but none of those helped.

Comment: After executing the above two commands i found the error: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10': File exists Suggest if any

Comment: What's the result of `ldd libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0`?

Answer (score 7):

Point 3 is close. You should however do

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```